# how to call sharepoint fast search web service from javascript?

Tags: javascript, web-services, authentication, sharepoint-2010, fastsearch

How can I call methods from sharepoint fast  search web service ex: QueryEx , GetQuerySuggestions 
I followed this 
[Article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pasen/archive/2012/04/01/using-sharepoint-2010-search-webservice-in-javascript-for-fast-search-for-sharepoint-2010.aspx)

but every time i get this error :

`<soap:envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode><faultstring>Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.</faultstring></soap:envelope>`

I also check the outgoing message with fiddler , and i found that the body is 0 and it returns "401 Unauthorized"
any ideas please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was Cross-domain calling from JavaScript  to WCF sevice , so I created a new web service in the same domain of the web application and consumed the other service from it .

javascript   ----call----> Proxy webservice    -----call-----> webservice in different domain