# How to query a search service and get back an xml string in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: xml, sharepoint, search, sharepoint-2010

In SharePoint 2010, I am making a web part and I want to be able to send a query to the search service and get back a XML string representing the result. How can I do this programatically?

Maybe a jquery ajax request is possible?

SharePoint does this basically with its own search web parts and the search boxes, so can this be done with out of the box tools, or do I need to download something extra?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

yes you can implement this task using jquery ajax requests , you have to call sharepoint search web service `"/_vti_bin/search.asmx` , you can find two useful examples here :

- [Using jQuery for Search in SharePoint](http://www.sharepointkings.com/2010/08/using-jquery-for-search-in-sharepoint.html)
- [Using SharePoint 2010 Search webservice in Javascript for FAST search for sharepoint 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pasen/archive/2012/04/01/using-sharepoint-2010-search-webservice-in-javascript-for-fast-search-for-sharepoint-2010.aspx)

**Note:** this will work only if this web part -contains javascript code- run under the same domain name -site name- as search service hosted else you will get **Cross-domain calling** problem .

you can solve this by a middle proxy web service [how to call sharepoint fast search web service from javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12243939/how-to-call-sharepoint-fast-search-web-service-from-javascript)